# Mock HttpFileColletion in Web API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, nunit, moq

In one of our classes I defined a .`Files` property that exposes
an instance of the `HttpFileCollection` class. At runtime this instance
will be retrieved from `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files`.

However, in the unit-testing context, there is no `HttpContext` to refer
to.
Usually, I'd allow the unit test to set up the instance of the
`HttpFileCollection` class to be returned by the tested class when
needed. However, `HttpFileCollection` does not seem to expose a
public .ctor, and it is sealed, so, in my unit tests I can't
instantiate one of them at all /tear.

Any suggestions on how to get around this problem ?

Thanks in advance,

I have to mock below method, This method is called from a controller. This method exist under different class:

```
public bool ValidateFiles(HttpFileCollection files)
  {
    if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
    {
        // Some code
        if (files[0].ContentLength > Constants.MaxFileSize)
        {
            //Some Code
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Some code
    }
 }
```

Comment: show your controller. avoid using `HttpContext` directly.

Comment: use `HttpFileCollectionBase`

Comment: Do you mean changing the parameter of existing method `ValidateFiles` from `HttpFileCollection` to `HttpFileCollectionBase` ?  and then write unit test case for it? If yes, then I am not allowed to change the method signature. I just have to write unit test case for it.  Is it possible to write unit test case without changing the existing implementation of `ValidateFiles` method?

Comment: Or Ultimately, Can you please share alternative code to perform above case?